# How do I get the total size of everything in a directory in one line?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, ls, disk-usage

I know I can use du -h to output the total size of a directory. But when it contains other subdirectories, the output would be something like:

```
du -h /root/test

.
.
.
.
24K   /root/test/1
64K   /root/test/2
876K  /root/test/3
1.1M  /root/test/4
15M   /root/test/5
17M   /root/test
```

I only want the last line because there are too many small directories in the `/root/test` directory. What can I do?

Comment: Just add the `-s` flag, `du -sh /root/test`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Add the `--max-depth` parameter with a value of 0:

```
du -h --max-depth=0 /root/test
```

Or, use the `-s` (summary) option:

```
du -sh /root/test
```

Either of those should give you what you want. For future reference, `man du` is very helpful.

Comment: +1 with a remark: certain implementations of `du` do not have the option `--max-depth` though (Busybox, for example). But the `-s` option does the trick in this case

Comment: `-s` is standard, `--max-depth` is GNU specific. The short version (`-d`) will also work in FreeBSD. `-h` is not standard but supported by a few implementations.

Comment: when using `-s`, sometimes I got warnings like: `du: cannot access \`/root/test/8393.jpg.tmp': No such file or directory`. What should I do to ignore this? I mean, not solve the warning but don't let `du` to output it.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: `2>/dev/null` will cause stderr to be ignored

Comment: Thanks! Remarks: On macOS 11 Big Sur the option needed for `du` is `-d` (as in "depth"). `du -d 0` only gives you the size of your current directory (".") without listing the directories in it. `du -d 1` if you want a list of directories in the current directory and the total size they consume. `du -d 2` if you want to also get the sub-directories listed with their size too. And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

The tail and head command shall be used to display last and beginning of the list.

In this case use following command::

```
## Display the last ten items
du -h /root/test | tail 
## N = 1 last item, N = 30 Last 30 items.
du -h /root/test | tail -n N
```